# ASp.net Webform multiline textbox adds line break on page load automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

From last one/two weeks i am noticing that any multiline textbox that i am using  in asp.net web-form based website adds line-break  to textbox automatically.

This has never happened before i ma facing this issue with almost all asp.net webform websites

```
<textarea name="txtComment" rows="2" cols="20" id="txtComment" tabindex="4" class="comment-box">
</textarea>
```

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening. It gets bad when we update the page & if we dont manually remove line breaks it will keep on adding linebreak to multiline textbox. I am not sure if this issue is due to some windows update or browser. It happens in Firefox & later i noticed same in Chrome?

Not sure why this is happening

Example: Code

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3"> Line </asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```

**HTML Rendered Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./TESTMultiline.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNjQ0NTE4MDYwZGRecdSIl8wWZzLW33b1SXrfQmgMkA==" />
</div>

    <div>
        <input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" />

        <textarea name="TextBox2" rows="3" cols="20" id="TextBox2">&#13;&#10; Line </textarea>
    </div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="F8195D5B" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAN9qVvxr9edjD9ICF1fyY9rESCFkFW/RuhzY1oLb/NUVB2nXP6dhZn6mKtmTGNHd3PbNvMJfATDdpnltdJAG8xg/EABZA==" />
</div></form>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"b33e31c27a494a9c8d0d82b3f5432ca7"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:61571/7d590f801da8489ebffe28d952f8f4af/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the whole aspx ?

Comment: Source Code or HTML Source?

Comment: HTML...............

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I have created a test page in this you can see Code, HTML and screenshot page in browser

Comment: `&#13;&#10; ` line break...remove it

Comment: Problem is that it automatically adds it `&#13;&#10;` on pageload?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181874/discussion-between-learning-and-royi-namir).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is related to the way the TextBox Control is being rendered. Changing the value for controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion in web.config did the trick for me:

```
controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion=4.5
```

The information is from the question [Extra characters added to multiline textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827198/extra-characters-added-to-multiline-textbox), answer from JTapp/jmoreno.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this issue for long as i was not able to find an solution or route cause of problem, just adding this in as `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.5" >` solved issue.

Comment: Do you know why textareas are being rendered wrong in later version of asp.net? Is there a way to fix the problem rather than working-around it? Is it just yet another reason to migrate away from asp.net forms?

Answer (score 0):

just remove `&#13;&#10;` from this row

```html
<textarea name="TextBox2" rows="3" cols="20" id="TextBox2"> Line </textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not be aware of this comment

Comment: The <textarea> is generated by asp.net - he does not have a direct control of what's in it: i.e. he cannot remove the chars directly

Comment: @Snufkin which makes me think about css `:after/before{ content:...}` or something like that

Comment: I tried to test the page and the problem did not appear after deleting `&#13;&#10;`

Comment: Fix which i am using on other website is  `TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Trim();` but this not a solution.  using this approach it will only add one line break and if i remove this like of quote then it will add one line break for each postback.. Which mean N linebreaks for N number of postbacks

Comment: @learning can you try this in incognito mode ? ( suspecting extensions)

Comment: @Learning yes it adds a line break

Comment: @RoyiNamir, Yes i tried in private mode.. it still adds line break

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Remove the space before the "**_**Line" in your source code: probably an unwonted character is 'hiding' there
2. Try remove text all together - and adding it in the code behind: `TextBox2.Text = "Line";`

**Edited:**

3. Open Chrome dev tool and check all css/classes/styling that effects this tag

Comment: I have tried all these tricks, I removed whole textbox, created new test pages but it keeps adding line-break to multi-line textbox

Comment: Just to mention this started happening with old website from last few weeks as this was not noticed before... Asp.net webform website which use bootstrap dont have this issue. Even a simple page as shown in example has this issue. so i am not sure why or what is causing it.

Comment: now that you have mentioned bootstrap, looks like this is a "center" issue: since you have 3 lines - some styling puts the text in the middle one. try change it to 5 lines and see the results :)

Comment: you should open chrome dev tool and check all classes / styling that effects this tag

Comment: That is fine but in the example i am not using any css. It just simple form with two controls, so i dont think it is CSS issue. and if was css then why it started showing this problem for last few weeks. No Frustrating... I am thinking may be due to some Microsoft update?

Comment: I really doubt it that Microsoft added extra chars in their render mechanism. however it can be that some updated/new NuGet or default project styling that has changed is causing it. try checking it with dev tool, the solution is probably hiding over there